# Problems with enemy launching & moving

Tags: java

I'm making a tankgame, I want the enemies to launch randomly.

```
package tanks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import menu.PlayPanel;
import menu.Tanks;

public class Enemy extends Character 
{
  int launchPosition;

  double distance;
  double deltaX, deltaY;

  public Player player;
  public Enemy enemy;

  public ArrayList<EnemyBullet> enemyBullets;


  public Enemy(PlayPanel panel) 
  {
     super("/objects/enemy tank.png", "/objects/enemy shooter.png");
     this.panel = panel;
     speed = 3 + rand.nextInt(5);
     maxHP = 80 + rand.nextInt(40); 
     HP = maxHP;

  }

  public void draw() 
  {
     launchPosition = rand.nextInt(3);

     switch(launchPosition)
     {
       case 0: //up
          x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
          y_pos =  ObjWH;
          angleCannon = 270;
          break;

       case 1: //left
          x_pos = ObjWH;
          y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
          angleCannon = 0;
          break;

       case 2: //under
          x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
          y_pos = Tanks.getSchermHoogte() - ObjWH;
          angleCannon = 90;
          break;

       case 3: //right
          x_pos = Tanks.getSchermBreedte()- ObjWH;
          y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
          angleCannon = 180;
          break;    
     }
  } 


  public void redraw() 
  {
     deltaX = Math.abs(player.x_pos - enemy.x_pos);
     deltaY = Math.abs(player.y_pos - enemy.y_pos);

     angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

     distance =  Math.sqrt((Math.pow(deltaX, deltaX) + Math.pow(deltaY, 
    deltaY)));

     x_move = speed*(deltaX/distance);
     y_move = speed*(deltaY/distance);

    /*
     x_move = speed*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
     y_move = speed*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
    */

     x_pos += x_move;
     y_pos += y_move;



     if (shoot)
     {
        shootAngle = angleCannon;
        shootTimer.start();
     }

  }

}
```

The enemies always launch in the upper left corner + they don't move towards the player. I don't really know why both these things happen.

Comment: The upper-left corner is the origin of the co-ordinate system, so you should take a look at what ´getSchermHoogte()´ and ´getSchermBreedte()´ are giving you.  It's possible they're both returning 0 or 1.

Comment: If they're not moving, are you sure the ´redraw()´ method is being called?

Answer (score 2):

The upper left corner is (0, 0) of the coordinate system. Most likely, you're multiplying x_pos and/or y_pos somewhere with 0 or do something else that will get them very close to 0.

`distance =  Math.sqrt((Math.pow(deltaX, deltaX) + Math.pow(deltaY, deltaY)));`

This line is wrong. Take a look at the documentation of [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)). You want to square deltaX and deltaY but it's not actually what you're doing. You are calculating deltaX^deltaX and deltaY^deltaY which are both probably pretty big. After taking the square root you divide something else by this large distance value. That will probably be something close to 0.

As evident by the other answer there are probably more mistakes in your code. The best way would be to use a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to execute the program step-by-step and watch what happens to the values of x_pos and y_pos. You will find your problem(s) very quickly that way (possibly even quicker than asking here).

Comment: thank you very much for the Math.pow comment, i must have been very distracted writing that. I found out i didn't call the draw() function in the constructor. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One problem seems to be here

```
deltaX = Math.abs(player.x_pos - enemy.x_pos);
deltaY = Math.abs(player.x_pos - enemy.x_pos);
```

deltaX and deltaY have the same value.

Comment: @ NaN, ah yes thank you, but this doesn't change the place the enemy launches....